# password_verify() returns nothing

Tags: php, sql, authentication, password-hash

I am passing the correct email and password in the login form. The Code gets the right hashed password from the Database. The function **password_verify()** returns nothing. Neither true or false. Did I do anything wrong there?

```
//Login User
    public function login($email, $password){
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $this->db->bind(':email', $email);


        $row = $this->db->single();

        $hashed_password = $row->password;
        $var_dump = password_verify($password, $hashed_password);
        echo $var_dump;

        if($var_dump){
            return $row;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am hashing the password in a register function:

```
//Hash Password
   $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/231316) in PHP set to be completely on?

Comment: in php `false` outputs nothing, show `print_r($row)`

Comment: `var_dump($var_dump);`